# Cannot see text in TextInputEditText after set its background color in Android Xamarin

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-textinputedittext

I have a TextInputEditText as below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tilEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etEmail"
            android:hint="@string/Email"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

However, if I set the background color for the TextInputEditText, the hint Text disappeared.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tilEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etEmail"
            android:hint="@string/Email"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I am trying to put it in style and then apply the style to the TextInputEditText but it does not work.

Anyone knows how I can customise it? I am working on Android in Xamarin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the hint text color to any color (other than your background color)

```
android:textColorHint="#110F10"
```

You may also want to set yout text color as well

```
android:textColor="#110F10"
```

Comment: I tried it already but it does not work. The whole EditText is white. Text only comes when the Input is on focus.

Comment: @LongDao, you mean even when the textColor is changed, you can see the text when the control is focused? I cannot reproduce this issue, have you clear your text in code behind when the focus is lost?